# User input happy birthday program

Tags: java, beginner, array, homework

For self-study homework I made a Java program that takes user input, creates people as objects, and says "Happy Birthday" to each person.

I am just wondering what mistakes I made here or how it could have been better.

**PERSON CLASS**

```
public class PeopleObjects{
    // For practice, make the people objects rather than just a list of names.

    private String name;
    private String birthDay;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(String myBirth){
        birthDay = myBirth;
    }

    public String getBirthDay(){
        return birthDay;
    }

}
```

**MAIN**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PeopleObjectsTestDrive{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList<PeopleObjects> listOfPeopleObjects = new ArrayList<PeopleObjects>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userChoice = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter any number other than 1 to start program."+"\n");

            while ((userChoice = input.nextInt()) != 1){

                PeopleObjects people = new PeopleObjects();

                System.out.println("\n###What is the name of the person?###\n");
                input.nextLine();//for some reason we have to use this twice to avoid bug
                people.setName(input.nextLine());

                System.out.println("\n###What is their birthday?###\n");
                people.setBirthDay(input.nextLine());
                listOfPeopleObjects.add(people);

                System.out.println("\nDo you want to quit and see list? Enter 1 for yes and 0 for no\n");
            }

            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n");

            for(int i=0; i < listOfPeopleObjects.size(); i++){

                if(listOfPeopleObjects.get(i).getName().equals("Joe")){
                    System.out.println("Happy Birthday Joe! You are special! Your birthday is on "+listOfPeopleObjects.get(i).getBirthDay()+" \n");
                }else if(i%2 == 0){
                    System.out.println("Happy Birthday to "+listOfPeopleObjects.get(i).getName()+".\n");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Happy Birthday to "+listOfPeopleObjects.get(i).getName()+" too!!!\n");

                }//end if else 
            }//end for
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. This looks interesting to me. Hope you learn a lot here.

Answer (score 6):

`PeopleObjects` is an odd name for a couple reasons:

- Both words are plural, even though each instance only represents a single person.
- Having "object" in the name is a little redundant. It's implied that the class is representing an  object.

I'd just call the class `Person`.

And you didn't give `PeopleObjects` a constructor. You're constructing an instance of the class ahead of time, then asking for input and calling the `set`ters. What if you forgot to set the birthday or name? They would be left as `null` and potentially cause problems later. If properties are required (which both name and birthday would presumably be), have them supplied by a constructor:

```
public Person(String name, String birthDay) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthDay = birthDay;
}

. . .

List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter any number other than 1 to start program."+"\n");

while (input.nextInt() != 1){
        // This is needed since nextInt doesn't consume the newline
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\n###What is the name of the person?###\n");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\n###What is their birthday?###\n");
        String birthday = input.nextLine();

        Person person = new Person(name, birthday);

        people.add(person);

        System.out.println("\nDo you want to quit and see list? Enter 1 for yes and 0 for no\n");
}
```

I changed a few things about that loop:

- As mentioned above, the person isn't constructed until the necessary data is already obtained, and the data is passed directly to the constructor.
- `userChoice` was never used. It was just storing the users entry, but that choice was only ever used in the condition. If you really wanted it for debugging purposes, it may be appropriate, but I didn't think that it was necessary here.
- I renamed the list of people to simply `people`. This was replacing your `PeopleObjects people = new PeopleObjects();` line. Again, calling a single person `people` is confusing. I also changed the type of `people` to `List`, from `ArrayList`. Always use the broadest type possible. In this case, you don't need any operations specific to `ArrayList`; you're only using `List` methods. To see why this is important, give [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/232359/understanding-programming-to-an-interface) a read over. Note the example used in the question.

---

Your other loop at the bottom is sub-optimal as well. First, you're constantly writing `people.get(i)`. For an `ArrayList`, `get` is very fast, but those calls are causing unneeded bloat. Create an intermediate variable `person` in the loop to neaten things up:

```
for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    Person person = people.get(i);
    String name = person.getName();

    if(name.equals("Joe")) {
        System.out.println("Happy Birthday Joe! You are special! Your birthday is on "
                           + person.getBirthDay() + " \n");

    } else if(i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Happy Birthday to " + name + ".\n");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Happy Birthday to " + name + " too!!!\n");
    }
}
```

I ended up creating a `name` variable as well since the name of the person was needed in multiple places.

You also had inconsistent spacing that I corrected. Some places had everything all smooshed together, and then other places (like with `==`) had spacing. I added spaces around all the operators, then broke up one of the longer lines. I also added empty lines after each `println` call so the cases were a little more distinct.

Unless you need the `i % 2 == 0` check to give a special message to every arbitrary second person, this loop could be slightly simplified by using an enhanced for-loop that doesn't rely on indices:

```
// Read as "for each person in people"
for(Person person : people) {
    String name = person.getName();

    if(name.equals("Joe")) {
        System.out.println("Happy Birthday Joe! You are special! Your birthday is on "
                           + person.getBirthDay() + " \n");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Happy Birthday to " + name + " too!!!\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Why `nextLine` after `nextInt`?

> ```
>             while ((userChoice = input.nextInt()) != 1){
>
>                 PeopleObjects people = new PeopleObjects();
>
>                 System.out.println("\n###What is the name of the person?###\n");
>                 input.nextLine();//for some reason we have to use this twice to avoid bug
> ```

While an explanatory comment is helpful, you may want to go ahead and search out the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/6660678):  essentially, the `nextInt` only reads as far as the end of the number; it does not read the succeeding end-of-line.  So if you want to read the next line, you have to first read that end-of-line so that you can start reading after it.  Once you do that, you might move that line higher, right after the `nextInt`.

I prefer comments to be on separate lines, although others disagree.

#### Favor interfaces over implementations

> ```
>         ArrayList<PeopleObjects> listOfPeopleObjects = new ArrayList<PeopleObjects>();
> ```

When defining a type, the general preference is to use the interface rather than the implementation.  So

```
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
```

This encourages you to code to the interface, only using methods that are available in the interface.  That in turn makes it easier to switch implementations.

In the more recent versions of Java, you don't need to specify the type parameter twice.  The second time you can just say `<>` and trust the compiler to figure it out.

`PersonObjects` is a plural name for a singular thing.  So we can just make that singular.  And there's not much point in saying that it is an object (which it actually isn't, it's a class).  Every instantiation of a class in Java is an object.  It could be just `Person`.

Similarly, `listOfPeopleObjects` could be just `people`.  There's some controversy over the `list`.  There is a notation called [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) where the type is included in the name.  I personally prefer to just use plural names for collections of objects.  But others disagree.

#### Clear prompts

> ```
>                 System.out.println("\nDo you want to quit and see list? Enter 1 for yes and 0 for no\n");
> ```

Why do you want to indicate yes?  Or no?  You want to indicate yes to quit and no to continue.  So why say yes and no?  Consider

```
                System.out.println("\nDo you want to quit and see list? Enter 1 to quit or 0 to continue\n");
```

Now we don't have to figure out what yes and no mean in this context (e.g. you could have been asking "Do you want to continue?" with everything else the same.

#### `do`/`while`

You may want to read up on the `do`/`while` syntax.  That would allow you to avoid asking for an initial response.  I.e. you wouldn't have to enter anything to start the processing.  Only to continue afterwards.

It would disrupt your current `nextInt`/`nextLine` pattern though.  You might consider how you could make that work.  Hint:  a custom method could do both commands in one unit of work.